# Urlencoding and toLowerCase - effect on output

Tags: java, url-encoding, tolower

I came through this code (java), and was wondering if below two will have any actual difference in output:

1. String output1 = (URLEncoder.encode(plainString, "UTF-8")).toLowerCase();
2. String output2 = URLEncoder.encode(plainString.toLowerCase(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Why dont you try it?

Comment: @Sybren Simple characters like "abc" work fine but I wasn't sure about the range of characters which is covered in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question why do you want to do lower case? URLs are case sensitive.

**To answer your question** - yes, there will be difference.

Using UTF-8 as the encoding scheme the string "The string ü@foo-bar" would get converted to "The+string+%C3%BC%40foo-bar" because in UTF-8 the character ü is encoded as two bytes C3 (hex) and BC (hex), and the character @ is encoded as one byte 40 (hex).

Now, in your this case - `(URLEncoder.encode(plainString, "UTF-8")).toLowerCase()` Hexa-decimal values will be converted to lower case.

Consider below example:

```
        String output1 = (URLEncoder.encode("ü@foo-Bar", "UTF-8")).toLowerCase();
        String output2 = URLEncoder.encode("ü@foo-Bar".toLowerCase(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(output1);
        System.out.println(output2);
```

Output:

```
%c3%bc%40foo-bar
%C3%BC%40foo-bar
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The results could differ: i tried it with "Ü" (german Umlaut) and output1 is `%c3%9c` whereas output2 is `%C3%BC`.